# Symfony Login form add extra fields

Tags: symfony

I have multiple firewalls on my app, and for one of them, I need to add one more field on the `symfony` login form.

In addition to the `username` and `password` I need to recover a field `"code"` that the user must complete to be logged on this firewall.

I saw that on the official `symfony` documentation :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

But I don't understand how to handle the new field from my form.

I don't use `fosuserbundle` and I don't need it for my use.

This is `symfony` advice  to create a custom form login for authentication system

```
// src/Security/TimeAuthenticator.php
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;

class TimeAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $exception) {
            // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
            // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $currentUser = $token->getUser();

        if ($currentUser instanceof UserInterface) {
            if ($currentUser->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The credentials were changed from another session.');
            }
        } else {
            if ('' === ($givenPassword = $token->getCredentials())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The given password cannot be empty.');
            }
            if (!$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $givenPassword)) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The given password is invalid.');
            }
        }

        $currentHour = date('G');
        if ($currentHour < 14 || $currentHour > 16) {
            // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
            // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                'You can only log in between 2 and 4!',
                array(), // Message Data
                412 // HTTP 412 Precondition Failed
            );
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            $user->getPassword(),
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

There is no extra field recovered in this example.

This is the default form login for `symfony` authentication, which I currently use :

```
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

I would like to add a field to this form and recover it in my custom `SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface` to execute my authentication logic, I need this extra field.

Thank you by advance for your advice.

Comment: You should be more specific about what is your problem.

Comment: I tried to be more specific.

Comment: You should try this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the additional request parmeters into the class, you can injected the `RequestStack` into you `TimeAuthenticator`:

```
class TimeAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function getOneTimeToken() : ?string
    {
        $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->request->get('yourNewField', null);
    }
    //...
```

Then use the new method to check the submitted value against the user in the `authenticateToken()` method.

Also check the GuardAuthenticator system, as it is more suited for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I I had seen official documentation on guardautheticator, but i did not anderstand how to recover my new field from my form login.